# How to auto scale dynamoDB provisioned throughput using cloud formation templates (CFTS)?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, autoscaling

It is possible to auto scale dynamodb tables provisioned read and write capacity using AWS Console.

Is there anyway to auto scale using CFTs.

Comment: Too old to answer, but if anyone lands up here, this is how you can do it: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/how-to-use-aws-cloudformation-to-configure-auto-scaling-for-amazon-dynamodb-tables-and-indexes/

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but DynamoDB now supports 'On demand' throughput rather than provisioned. [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-dynamodb-table.html#cfn-dynamodb-table-billingmode). This is an alternative to auto-scaling, but pricing may be higher.

Set the property `BillingMode` to `PAY_PER_REQUEST`

There is no need to then set the `ProvisionedThroughput`

Example YAML:

```
  TableName:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      TableName: TableName
      BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
```

Answer (score -1):

The provisioned read and write capacity units describe the minimum number of consistent read and write throughput. This is the minimum performance guarantee from AWS. If you wish to increase this limit, one way to do it is to use the "Update Stack" functionality provided in the AWS CloudFormation. The pre-requisite for this is the original DynamoDB tables should have been created through a CF template.

Also, DynamoDB unlike the RDS service does not support auto-scaling.

Attaching some useful links.
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-updating-stacks-update-behaviors.html
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-dynamodb-table.html#cfn-dynamodb-table-provisionedthroughput

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

As of Jun 2017 AWS provides their own Dynamodb Auto Scaling solution. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/AutoScaling.html

Cloud Formation Example: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-dynamodb-table.html#cfn-dynamodb-table-examples-application-autoscaling